# C# deserialize JSON problem with missing attribute

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a problem to deserialize a json object by using javascriptserialize method  with  sometimes missing attribute. I'm new in C# deserailize
here is the json ouptut:

```
{"result": [{"id": "1", "inc_group": {"link": "XXX","value": "222"}},{"id": "2","inc_group": ""},{"id": "3","inc_group": {"link": "YYY","value": "654"}}] }
```

the attribute inc_group can be empty sometimes.
Here is my sample script:

```
public class inc_group
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public inc_group inc_group { get; set; }
 }

public class Root
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }

}

 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var json_Dictionary = js.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

Here is the error message:
extract JSON [2]: System.InvalidOperationException: Impossible to convert an object type 'System.String' to 'ScriptMain+Inc_Group'

this error appears when it deserializes the json

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below class

```
public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object inc_group { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}


Root items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Using JavaScript Deserialization

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
Root items = js.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

I have tried with above class and its parsing Json and converting to C# object without any error.

Parsing data will be done as below if you are using JavaScriptSerializer

```
foreach (var item in items.result)
{
    dynamic obj = item.inc_group;
    if (obj is string)
    {
         string strValue = obj;
    }
    else
    {
         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in obj)
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",
                     kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
         }
     }
}
```

If you are using NewtonSoft JsonConvert.Deserialize method then it will be something like this.

```
foreach (var item in items.result)
{
   dynamic obj = item.inc_group;
   if (obj is string)
   {
       string strValue = obj;
   }
   else
   {
       string link = obj.link;
       string value = obj.value;
   }
}
```

Comment: thks Bhaveh for your reply. This model may be worked with newton.json but how to translate it with javascriptserialize method?

Comment: Visit https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/

Hope this will help to do it using Javascript Serialize/Deserialize method.

Comment: Thanks Bhaveh. You’re right. There is no problem anymore by doing this. My last question is, how can i parse the object inc_group to retrieve the value and the link?

Comment: Here is my error message when i deserialize the object class: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]. Thx in advance.

Comment: Ref for the Key Value pair part : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Amazing Bhavesh, it woks fine. You saved me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Result` definition, put `public inc_group? inc_group` to show that that field is [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types), and thus doesn't always have to contain a value, and the deserialisation should work.

Also set set [JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#ignore-null-when-deserializing) setting to true.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your answer.  I updated the Result definition based on your comment. It raise me the error message: the type must be a non-nullable value type. Do i need to update the inc_group definition?

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#ignore-null-when-deserializing